# Is the following statement true: $((A \Rightarrow B) \wedge (B \in C)) \Rightarrow A \in C$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Just came up with problem that seems to be very basic, but I can't figure it out. I'm pretty certain it's not true. A, B are logical sentences and C is a set. Can you prove that below statement is true, or give a counterexample to show it's false?

$((A \Rightarrow B) \wedge (B \in C)) \Rightarrow A \in C$?

Comment: For sets $A, B$, what does $A\Rightarrow B$ mean?

Comment: $A\Rightarrow B$ is a statement about propositions, not about sets. And if that is indeed what is meant here, the answer is *no*: let $C=\{B\}$, and let $A$ be any proposition distinct from $B$ that implies $B$. Then $B\in C$, but $A\notin C$.

Comment: @paw88789 sorry, A and B are logical sentences

Comment: So $C$ is a set that contains a logical sentence as an element.  Is that correct?

Comment: @paw88789 by belonging to C, I meant having certain property C

Comment: @StanisławMaksicki Can you clarify more what is $C$? Is it a property? Is it a set?

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari I think BrianM.Scott answered the question. Originally my problem was following: if B has  a certain property and A implies B, then is it the case that A has this property.

Comment: @Stanisłav: I’ve written it up as an answer so that we can get the question off the unanswered list. I took your comments into account to make $C$ a little more interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’ve slightly modified what I wrote in my comment to make $C$ correspond to a more interesting property than simply *is identical to* $B$.

Take $C$ to be the set of all propositions logically equivalent to $B$, and take $A$ to be any proposition such that $A\Rightarrow B$ and $B\not\Rightarrow A$; then $B\in C$, but $A\notin C$.